# Permanecer estilo do hover ao abrir um submenu Dropdown

Tags: html, css, menu, dropdown, submenu

Preciso que a cor do `hover` permaneça ao abrir o submenu.
Meu submenu funciona, só quero que fique marcado o menu o qual ele está vinculado.
Segue o código de exemplo:

**HTML:**

```
<ul>
  <li><a href="#">Link 1  &raquo;</a>
      <ul>
          <li><a href="#">Link 2</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Link 3</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Link 4</a></li>
      </ul>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#">Link 2</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Link 3</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Link 4</a></li>
</ul>
```

**CSS:**

```
ul {
    width: 200px;
    background: #ccc;
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0;
    border: 1px solid #999;
}

ul li {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #999;
    position: relative;
}

ul li:last-child {
    border-bottom: none;
}

ul li a {
    color: #000;
    display: block;
    padding: 5px;
}

ul li a:hover {
    background:#999;
}

ul li ul {
    display:none;
    position: absolute;
    top:0;
    left: 200px;
}

ul li:hover > ul {
    display: block;
}
```

Pode vê-lo em funcionamento aqui: http://jsfiddle.net/ze8xtpxt/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Isto é possível alcançar com uma pequena mudança no teu código CSS.

Primeiro vamos aplicar uma `class` à lista principal para que seja mais facil trabalhar com ela e para apontarmos com mais precisão aquilo que queremos modificar ou aplicar estilos, para evitar possíveis conflitos no futuro com outras listas.

Esta class vai se chamar `.menu` por exemplo, que aplicada no código HTML ficará:

```
<ul class="menu">
    <li><a href="#">Link 1  &raquo;</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Link 2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Link 3</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Link 4</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Link 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Link 3</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Link 4</a></li>
</ul>
```

De seguida iremos então fazer a tal simples modificação no código CSS.
Se reparares no teu código CSS, tens algo como:

```
ul li a:hover {
    background:#999;
}
```

Nós iremos substituir este bocado de código com o código abaixo, que irá fazer o mesmo trabalho que ele já estava a fazer, só que ele agora irá também aplicar o estilo pretendido, que é ficar como ativo (ou seja com aquela cor de *background* cinzento mais escuro) quando estamos a fazer `hover` sobre o sub-menu.

```
.menu li:hover > a {
    background:#999;
}
```

> Aqui tens o resultado e **[exemplo online no jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6aLL5r4n/)**.

Comment: Era isso mesmo! Muito obrigado!